# Trouble passing PO parameter to new Items

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, model, controller, parameter-passing

I have models for POs and for Items. Items belong to POs. I would like for Item.po_id to be set to the current Po.id when creating a new item, but when the form submits, it fails validation because the Po is blank.

In views/pos/show.html.erb, I have the link where I try to pass the PO id to the new item:

```
    <%= link_to 'Add items', new_item_path(:item => {:po_id => @po.id}) %>
```

In items_controller.rb, I have:

```
def new
  @item = Item.new(params[:po_id])
  @item.po_id = params[:po_id]
end
```

And I have not included a field for po_id in the Item form, as it should not be alterable by the user.

Again, at this point, the form submission fails validation because "Po can't be blank"

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it wrong. As per your code, `params[:po_id]` should be `params[:item][:po_id]` as you are passing `:po_id` inside the `:item` in the `link_to`

Comment: Not sure that I understand. So, the code would look like this?   
`def new
    @item = Item.new(params[:item][:po_id])
    @item.po_id = params[:item][:po_id]
end`

I get thrown an error: When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument.

Sorry for the basic questions - I'm new at this.

Comment: `@item = Item.new(params[:item][:po_id])

Comment: @Coalsand Just change it to `@item = Item.new`

Comment: That didn't solve the issue, but I think I see what the problem is: When I submit the form, the parameters being passed do not include po_id because it is not a field in the form. When I include po_id as a text field in the form, it succeeds. I think that I can just go hidden_field with the po_id in the form, but for a cleaner solution, how would I go about adding po_id as a parameter upon submitting the form directly?

Comment: @Coalsand There is no way other than putting a `hidden_field` unless you are storing it in a session.